# Search only for the first (couple of) eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I would like to solve an eigenvalue problem for a PDE by a finite difference method. Therefore my problem is reduced to a matrix eigenvalue problem. The thing is that the size of this matrix will be quite large, and if I use the function `eig` it searches for ALL the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which in my case is a waste of time.

Is there a possibility to make the eigenvalue algorithm stop after finding the first k eigenvalues? (where k is a small positive integer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use [`eigs`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) to return the K largest or smallest eigenvalues.

Example: `eigs(A,[],K)` will return the `K` largest-magnitude eigenvectors of matrix `A`.

Comment: Two blog entries you might like: [finding eigenfunctions via numerical iteration](http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/85743.html) and [solving the schrödinger equation numerically](http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/86063.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`eigs`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html). From `help eigs`:

> Find a few eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix